# How to check if installation finished successfully - install4j

Tags: install4j

I know there's a "Finish Screen" to show the end of the installation. I want to create my own Finish Screen dependly on the result of my installation (success/failure). 
How can I get this information?

The behaviour should be exactly the same as the "Uninstallation failure/success" Screens on the uninstaller side.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "Configurable banner form" screen and select the "Quit after screen" property.

The behavior of the "Uninstallation failure" screen cannot be implemented with a custom screen.